# How to determine View's background colour?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the colour values of my background. The background colour of my application is set to randomise on a button press, but I want to be able to then get the values of that colour in the background and determine what colour that is. This is what I got from my research but whenever I print the results to the console I just get 0s. Any help is really appreciated!

```
func getBackgroundColor(){
    let color = self.view.backgroundColor

    let colour = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

    self.view.backgroundColor = color

    var red = CGFloat()
    var green = CGFloat()
    var blue = CGFloat()
    var alpha = CGFloat()

    print(red, green, blue, alpha)

    color!.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

}
```

Comment: Check the return value of  the call to `getRed(_:green:,blue:alpha:)`. If it returns `false` then the color couldn't be treated as an RGB color. It might help if you show how you set the background color.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let red = self.view.backgroundColor?.ciColor.red
        let blue = self.view.backgroundColor?.ciColor.blue
        let green = self.view.backgroundColor?.ciColor.green
        let alpha = self.view.backgroundColor?.ciColor.alpha

        print("r \(red) b \(blue) g \(green) a \(alpha) ")
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, it crashes whenever I call the function

Comment: Try getting this if this code crashes   var color = self.view.backgroundColor
        var fRed: CGFloat = 0
        var fGreen: CGFloat = 0
        var fBlue: CGFloat = 0
        var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0
        if (color?.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha))! {
            print("color \(fRed)  \(fGreen)  \(fBlue)")
        } else {
            print("error: color could not be converted")
        }